# Connecting from MEAN stack app to MongoDB running on AWS

Tags: angular, mongodb, amazon-web-services, express, mean-stack

I am in the process of building a MEAN stack application. I have mongodb running live on AWS and connect to it just fine using Robo 3T.

So I was trying to code the connection in the express angular application I am building. However no matter how I type the connection I just get a connection timeout error. so I need  help. Now in Robo 3t the way I connected to it was simply using localhost and then my ssh key information and it connects to the database.

Here is my server.js code for this portion:
// server.js

```
const express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    config = require('../config/DB');

    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connect(config.DB).then(
      () => {console.log('Database is connected') },
      err => { console.log('Can not connect to the database'+ err)}
    );
```

So as you can see I've stored my variable code for the connection string inside of a DB.js file with a var of DB.

```
// DB.js

module.exports = {
  DB: 'mongodb://serveripaddres:27017/databasename'
};
```

As you can see above i've removed the ip address for the database and also the databasename I know typically you can also include the admin username password in this string. However my attempts doing that have also failed. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Oh the app runs on a separate server then the database. I realized yes it could be easier to set these items both up on the same server but that's not how I want it structured.

Thank you!

Comment: install mongo clinet on the instance where you running your apps and verify that is it accessbile from your instance, once u get access its mean issue with code not with access , if not accessible then check securty group of your database instacne is it allowing 27017 port for public trafic or from the instance you want to connect

Comment: The database needs to be on a separate instance for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF security port is allowing traffic from other instance then the issue with config.

Do the following

Edit your MongoDB config file. On Ubuntu:

```
sudo vim /etc/mongod.conf
```

Look for the net line and comment out the bindIp line under it, which is currently limiting MongoDB connections to localhost:

Make sure in your /etc/mongodb.conf file you have the following line,

```
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
```

Now restart mongodb

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your computer Ip address in your aws for security reason that why getting denied. and check for credentials as well.

Comment: I'm not accessing it from my computer directly I'm accessing it from the other instance.